# Django Custom Queryset Using Listview if Parameters Exist in URL

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views, django-listview

I have a listview for my blog:

```
#views.py
class BlogListView(ListView):
    model = Blog
    template_name = 'blog/index.html'
    context_object_name = 'blogs'
    ordering = ['-date_posted']
    paginate_by = 5

#urls.py 
path('', BlogListView.as_view(), name='blog-index'),
```

In my model I have different type of blogs, such as video blog or text blog. my model is like this:

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    TYPE = (
        ('Video', 'Video'),
        ('Text', 'Text'),
    )
    type = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=TYPE, default='Text')
```

Now I want to use `request.GET.get('type')` to query different types. For example if I go to the url, `127.0.0.1:8000/?type=video` I want only blog that are the type video to show. Is it possible to do this with only this listview, or do I have to create others. I need help with making of this feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yes**, you can implement this in the `ListView` by overriding the [**`.get_queryset(…)`** method [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/mixins-multiple-object/#django.views.generic.list.MultipleObjectMixin.get_queryset):

```
class BlogListView(ListView):
    model = Blog
    template_name = 'blog/index.html'
    context_object_name = 'blogs'
    ordering = ['-date_posted']
    paginate_by = 5

    def get_queryset(self):
        type = self.request.GET.get('type')
        qs = super().get_queryset()
        if type is not None:
            return qs.filter(type__iexact=type)
        return qs
```